# How to add a column to a DataFrame based on a multi-index map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
# df.head(10)
          TYPE               A                  B  
0            0               5                 25     
1            1               7                 23     
2            5              10                 43     
3            1               5                 37     
4            2               4                 61     
5            3               1                 17   
6            0               8                 39     
7            2               4                 59  
8            4               2                  6  
9            0               3                 31
```

And I have a multi-index map `mapp` as follows:

```
# mapp.head(10)
                  num  
AA      BB             
1        1          1 
         4          2 
         5          3 
        10          4 
        17          5 
        18          6 
2        3          7
         6          8
         9          9
3        3         10
```

I want to add a column `df['num']` like this:

```
          TYPE               A                  B           num
0            0               5                 25            74
1            1               7                 23            89
2            5              10                 43           129
3            1               5                 37            77
4            2               4                 61            62
5            3               1                 17             5
6            0               8                 39            98
7            2               4                 59            61
8            4               2                  6             8
9            0               3                 31            40
```

I try to realize it by using the following code:

```
idx = df.set_index(['A', 'B']).index
df['num'] = mapp.loc[idx, 'num']
```

But Python throws an Exception:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

How can I fix it? Or is there any other method to solve this problem? Besides, the size of `df` is very large, I prefer not to use the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.join(mapp, on=['A','B'])
print (df1)
   TYPE   A   B  num
0     0   5  25  NaN
1     1   7  23  NaN
2     5  10  43  NaN
3     1   5  37  NaN
4     2   4  61  NaN
5     3   1  17  5.0
6     0   8  39  NaN
7     2   4  59  NaN
8     4   2   6  8.0
9     0   3  31  NaN
```

Comment: How foolish am I! I actually forgot join!! Thank u very much.